# Postman: changing value of a local variable impacts value of environment variable

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm wondering if I ran into a bug in Postman, or if this is by design.

I have a case in which I have 2 requests:

In request 1, I capture the full `responsebody`.

In request 2 (`put`) I need to provide the captured `responsebody` of request 1 as `requestbody` for request 2 **but** with a minimal change in certain booleans.

In additional requests (`put`) I do the same thing as in request 2. So again start from the captured `responsebody` of request 1.

Therefore I used the following approach:

Request 1 - Test script:

```
pm.environment.set("Filter-get_responsebody", pm.response.json());
```

Request 2 - Pre-request script:

```
var res_body = pm.environment.get("Filter-get_responsebody");

console.log(pm.environment.get("Filter-get_responsebody"));
//==>returns the full json response as captured in request 1

res_body.Filters[2].List[0].Checked = true;
console.log(pm.environment.get("Filter-get_responsebody"));
//==>returns the full json response but already with the updated boolean done in the var res_body

res_body.Filters[2].IsChanged=true;
console.log(pm.environment.get("Filter-get_responsebody"));
//==>returns the full json response but already updated by the 2 changes on var res_body

pm.environment.set("ProductList-Put-SelectFirstFuelType-RequestBody",JSON.stringify(res_body));
```

So in the pre-request script of request 2 my original environment variable (`Filter-get_responsebody`) gets an updated value although I am not directly altering its value. Instead on the first line I stored the environment variable value into a local script variable (`res_body`). Doing so allows me to reuse the original response body of request 1 in other requests.

So my question is: how come the environment variable gets an updated value while I am not directly altering it. Is this a bug in the postman scripting engine? I have setup a dummy test in which I had 2 request with the same approach, but instead of having a JSON object, I just used a string value to put and update in the environment variable. In that case, values are not overwritten. However, when updating the JSON (as in above described example), it overwrites the value directly in the environment variable.

Comment: Are the way that the variable scopes work, something that might provide some information about the way they are stored and updated? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Comment: Well, not really in this case. The fact is just, if I create a script variable (res_body in this case) and have it store a value of an environment variable, why is the environment variable value updated once I update the value of a local script variable. These 2 should not have a link, right?

Comment: Have you presented this problem to the Postman team on their GitHub account? They would be able to give you a yes/no answer and potentially fix it, if it’s an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am creating a bug as we speak ;-)